# How can I use OSX to share an internet connection WITHOUT being a DHCP server?

Tags: macos, networking, router

I have a small network of single-board linux computers (beaglebone blacks running Arch if it matters) that I would like to route to the internet by way of my Macbook's wifi.  There are two complicating factors: 1) I can't use 192.168.2.0 (the Macbook's default Internet Sharing network), and 2) one of the linux boxen (boarden?) is acting as the DHCP server.

So what I'm trying to do is configure OSX (10.10 if it matters) to get an IP via DHCP on both the ethernet and the wifi, and then route traffic from the computers on the ethernet to wifi and from there on to the internet.  Can this be done?  If so, how?  I assume the answer will involve NAT somehow, but I'll need more hand holding than that, I'd like to understand this and my last real IT experience is >10 years old at this point.